# Extracting the extent of a shapefile in excel format

Tags: excel, gis, arcgis

[like in this image, the extent of a layer file is given as Top, Right, Bottom and Left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRKKL.jpg)

Is there any method that I can extract those extent data in excel format?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the metadata from ArcCatalog or ArcMap. Metadata contain the information about extent.
If you need more information from metadata change Metadata style into "ISO 19139 Metadata Implementation specification" or any others.
This can be done by 
Customize > ArcMap Option > MetaData